# Error on MPI while executing REGCM

Tags: command-line, 20.04, mpi, interrupts

While starting a simulation on REGCM, I executed the command

```
mpirun -np 2 ./bin/regcmMPI sensitivity01.in
```

Which gives me the following:

```
This is RegCM trunk
   SVN Revision:  compiled at: data : Sep  9 2021  time: 18:24:31

 : this run start at  : 2021-09-27 12:04:43-0400
 : it is submitted by : jorgenava
 : it is running on   : jorgenava-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx
 : it is using        :            1   processors
 : in directory       : /home/jorgenava/Modelos_de_Simulacion/RegCM-master/Regrun
                       
 CPUS DIM1 =            1
 CPUS DIM2 =            1

 Reading model namelist file
 Using default dynamical parameters.
 Using default hydrostatc parameters.
 Using default cloud parameter.
 -------------- FATAL CALLED ---------------
  Fatal in file: mod_params.F90 at line:     2699
 Error reading GRELLPARAM
 -------------------------------------------
 mod_params.F90 :     2699:            1
 Abort called by computing node            0 at 2021-09-27 12:04:43.080 -0400
 Execution terminated because of runtime error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 0 in communicator MPI COMMUNICATOR 3 DUP FROM 0
with errorcode 1.

NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.
You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on
exactly when Open MPI kills them.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
It seems that [at least] one of the processes that was started with
mpirun did not invoke MPI_INIT before quitting (it is possible that
more than one process did not invoke MPI_INIT -- mpirun was only
notified of the first one, which was on node n0).

mpirun can *only* be used with MPI programs (i.e., programs that
invoke MPI_INIT and MPI_FINALIZE).  You can use the "lamexec" program
to run non-MPI programs over the lambooted nodes.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The contents of the file sensitivity01.in are the following:

```
!dominio 25 km CORDEX SUDAMERICA
!GRELL/LAND-EMANUEL/OCEAN=sensit01
 &dimparam
 iy     = 278,
 jx     = 243,
 kz     = 18,
 nsg    = 1,
 /
 &geoparam
 iproj = 'ROTMER',
 ds = 30.0, 
 ptop = 5.0,
 clat = -21.11,
 clon = -60.3,
 plat = -21.11,
 plon = -60.3,
 truelatl = -30.0,
 truelath = -60.0,
 i_band = 0,
 /
 &terrainparam
 domname = 'sensit01',
 lakedpth = .false.,
 fudge_lnd   = .false.,
 fudge_lnd_s = .false.,
 fudge_tex   = .false.,
 fudge_tex_s = .false.,
 dirter = '/home/jorgenava/Modelos_de_Simulacion/RegCM-master/Regrun/input',
 inpter = '/home/jorgenava/Modelos_de_Simulacion/Globedat/',
 /
 &debugparam
 debug_level = 0,
 /
 &boundaryparam
 nspgx  = 12,
 nspgd  = 12,
 /
 &globdatparam
 ibdyfrq = 6,
 ssttyp = 'OI_WK',
 dattyp = 'EIN15',
 gdate1 = 2000010100,
 gdate2 = 2000013100,
 dirglob = '/home/jorgenava/Modelos_de_Simulacion/RegCM-master/Regrun/input',
 inpglob = '/home/jorgenava/Modelos_de_Simulacion/Globedat',
 /
 &globwindow
 lat0 = 0.0
 lat1 = 0.0
 lon0 = 0.0
 lon1 = 0.0
 /
 &restartparam
 ifrest  = .false. ,
 mdate0  = 2000010100,
 mdate1  = 2000010100,
 mdate2  = 2000013100,
 /
 &timeparam
 dtrad   =    30.,
 dtabem  =    18.,
 dtsrf   =   600.,
 dt      =   30.,
 /
 &outparam
 ifsave  = .false. ,
   savfrq  =    0.,
 ifatm  = .true. ,
   atmfrq  =     6.,
 ifrad   = .false. ,
   radfrq  =     6.,
 ifsrf   = .true. ,
 ifsub   = .false. ,
   srffrq  =     3.,
 ifchem  = .false.,
   chemfrq =     6.,
 dirout='/home/jorgenava/Modelos_de_Simulacion/RegCM-master/Regrun/output',
 /
 &physicsparam
 iboudy  =          5,
 ibltyp  =          1,
 !idiffu   =          1, ! Diffusion scheme
 icup_lnd =         2,
 icup_ocn =         4,
 ipptls  =          1,
 iocnflx =          2,
 ipgf    =          0,
 iemiss  =          0,
 lakemod =          0,
 ichem   =          0,
 scenario = 'A1B',
 idcsst = 0,
 iseaice = 0,
 idesseas = 0,
 iconvlwp = 0,
 /
 &subexparam
 qck1land  = 0.0005,  ! Autoconversion Rate for Land
 qck1oce   = 0.0005,  ! Autoconversion Rate for Ocean
 gulland   = 0.65,    ! Fract of Gultepe eqn (qcth) when prcp occurs (land)
 guloce    = 0.30,    ! Fract of Gultepe eqn (qcth) for ocean
 cevaplnd  = 1.0e-5,  ! Raindrop evap rate coef land [[(kg m-2 s-1)-1/2]/s]
 cevapoce  = 1.0e-5,  ! Raindrop evap rate coef ocean [[(kg m-2 s-1)-1/2]/s]
 caccrlnd  = 6.0,     ! Raindrop accretion rate land  [m3/kg/s]
 caccroce  = 4.0,     ! Raindrop accretion rate ocean [m3/kg/s]
 conf      = 1.00,    ! Condensation efficiency 
 /
! &subexparam
! qck1land =   .250E-03,
! qck1oce  =   .250E-03,
! cevaplnd =   .100E-02,
! caccrlnd =      3.000,
! cftotmax =      0.75,

 /
 &grellparam
 igcc  = 1,          ! Cumulus closure scheme
                     !   1 => Arakawa & Schubert (1974)
                     !   2 => Fritsch & Chappell (1980)
 gcr0 = 0.0020,      ! Conversion rate from cloud to rain
 edtmin      = 0.20, ! Minimum Precipitation Efficiency land
 edtmin_ocn  = 0.20, ! Minimum Precipitation Efficiency ocean
 edtmax      = 0.80, ! Maximum Precipitation Efficiency land
 edtmax_ocn  = 0.80, ! Maximum Precipitation Efficiency ocean
 edtmino     = 0.20, ! Minimum Tendency Efficiency (o var) land
 edtmino_ocn = 0.20, ! Minimum Tendency Efficiency (o var) ocean
 edtmaxo     = 0.80, ! Maximum Tendency Efficiency (o var) land
 edtmaxo_ocn = 0.80, ! Maximum Tendency Efficiency (o var) ocean
 edtminx     = 0.20, ! Minimum Tendency Efficiency (x var) land
 edtminx_ocn = 0.20, ! Minimum Tendency Efficiency (x var) ocean
 edtmaxx     = 0.80, ! Maximum Tendency Efficiency (x var) land
 edtmaxx_ocn = 0.80, ! Maximum Tendency Efficiency (x var) ocean
 shrmin      = 0.30, ! Minimum Shear effect on precip eff. land
 shrmin_ocn  = 0.30, ! Minimum Shear effect on precip eff. ocean
 shrmax      = 0.90, ! Maximum Shear effect on precip eff. land
 shrmax_ocn  = 0.90, ! Maximum Shear effect on precip eff. ocean
 pbcmax = 50.0,      ! Max depth (mb) of stable layer b/twn LCL & LFC
 mincld = 150.0,     ! Min cloud depth (mb).
 htmin = -250.0,     ! Min convective heating
 htmax = 500.0,      ! Max convective heating
 skbmax = 0.4,       ! Max cloud base height in sigma
 dtauc = 30.0        ! Fritsch & Chappell (1980) ABE Removal Timescale (min)
 /
 &emanparam
 elcrit_ocn  = 0.0011D0,
 elcrit_lnd  = 0.0011D0,
 coeffr  = 1.0D0,
 /
 &holtslagparam
 /
 &clm_inparm
 fpftcon = 'pft-physiology.c130503.nc',
 fsnowoptics = 'snicar_optics_5bnd_c090915.nc',
 fsnowaging = 'snicar_drdt_bst_fit_60_c070416.nc',
 /
 &clm_soilhydrology_inparm
 /
 &clm_hydrology1_inparm
 /
```

What could be causing this problem?

EDIT:
If isntead I use the following command:

```
mpirun -n 4 ./bin/regcmMPI sensitivity01.in
```

I instead get the following output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Synopsis:       mpirun [options] <app> 
                mpirun [options] <where> <program> [<prog args>]

Description:    Start an MPI application in LAM/MPI.

Notes:
                [options]       Zero or more of the options listed below
                <app>           LAM/MPI appschema
                <where>         List of LAM nodes and/or CPUs (examples
                                below)
                <program>       Must be a LAM/MPI program that either
                                invokes MPI_INIT or has exactly one of
                                its children invoke MPI_INIT
                <prog args>     Optional list of command line arguments
                                to <program>

Options:
                -c <num>        Run <num> copies of <program> (same as -np)
                -client <rank>  <host>:<port>
                                Run IMPI job; connect to the IMPI server <host>
                                at port <port> as IMPI client number <rank>
                -D              Change current working directory of new
                                processes to the directory where the
                                executable resides
                -f              Do not open stdio descriptors
                -ger            Turn on GER mode
                -h              Print this help message
                -l              Force line-buffered output
                -lamd           Use LAM daemon (LAMD) mode (opposite of -c2c)
                -nger           Turn off GER mode
                -np <num>       Run <num> copies of <program> (same as -c)
                -nx             Don't export LAM_MPI_* environment variables
                -O              Universe is homogeneous
                -pty / -npty    Use/don't use pseudo terminals when stdout is 
                                a tty
                -s <nodeid>     Load <program> from node <nodeid>
                -sigs / -nsigs  Catch/don't catch signals in MPI application
                -ssi <n> <arg>  Set environment variable LAM_MPI_SSI_<n>=<arg>
                -toff           Enable tracing with generation initially off
                -ton, -t        Enable tracing with generation initially on
                -tv     Launch processes under TotalView Debugger
        -v              Be verbose
                -w / -nw        Wait/don't wait for application to complete
                -wd <dir>       Change current working directory of new
                                processes to <dir>
                -x <envlist>    Export environment vars in <envlist>

Nodes:          n<list>, e.g., n0-3,5
CPUS:           c<list>, e.g., c0-3,5
Extras:         h (local node), o (origin node), N (all nodes), C (all CPUs)

Examples:       mpirun n0-7 prog1
                Executes "prog1" on nodes 0 through 7.

                mpirun -lamd -x FOO=bar,DISPLAY N prog2
                Executes "prog2" on all nodes using the LAMD RPI.  
                In the environment of each process, set FOO to the value
                "bar", and set DISPLAY to the current value.

                mpirun n0 N prog3
                Run "prog3" on node 0, *and* all nodes.  This executes *2*
                copies on n0.

                mpirun C prog4 arg1 arg2
                Run "prog4" on each available CPU with command line
                arguments of "arg1" and "arg2".  If each node has a
                CPU count of 1, the "C" is equivalent to "N".  If at
                least one node has a CPU count greater than 1, LAM
                will run neighboring ranks of MPI_COMM_WORLD on that
                node.  For example, if node 0 has a CPU count of 4 and
                node 1 has a CPU count of 2, "prog4" will have
                MPI_COMM_WORLD ranks 0 through 3 on n0, and ranks 4
                and 5 on n1.

                mpirun c0 C prog5
                Similar to the "prog3" example above, this runs "prog5"
                on CPU 0 *and* on each available CPU.  This executes
                *2* copies on the node where CPU 0 is (i.e., n0).
                This is probably not a useful use of the "C" notation;
                it is only shown here for an example.

Defaults:       -c2c -w -pty -nger -nsigs
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Your output has `it is using        :            1   processors` which is suspicious. Make sure you use the mpirun that belongs with the MPI that you compile with.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout how do I do that?